# Dreamweaver CS6: How to apply 2 different text styles in one line?

Tags: css, html, dreamweaver

My heading is "DREAMWEAVER CS6 How to design a website" in **one** line only.

"DREAMWEAVER CS6" is bold, blue colour, uppercase.
"How to design a website" is light, black colour, lowercase.

How do I code this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap them in span elements.

```
<span style="font-weight:bold; color:#0000FF;">DREAMWEAVER CS6</span> <span style="color:#888888">How to design a website</span>
```